# NAN when Normalize double values

Tags: java, double, normalization

I am trying to calculate tfidf values for files and save them into a matrix, the tfidf values I want to normalize them between 0 and 1 first. 
But I have a problem, The first value calculated after normalization is NAN, how can I fix this problem.

This is what I did

```
    double tf; //term frequency
    double idf; //inverse document frequency
    double tfidf = 0; //term frequency inverse document frequency 
    double minValue=0.0;
    double maxValue=0;
    File output = new File("E:/hsqldb-2.3.2/hsqldb-2.3.2/hsqldb/hsqldb/matrix.txt");
    FileWriter out = new FileWriter(output); 
    mat= new String[termsDocsArray.size()][allTerms.size()];
    int c=0; //for files
    for (String[] docTermsArray : termsDocsArray) {
        int count = 0;//for words
        for (String terms : allTerms) {
            tf = new TfIdf().tfCalculator(docTermsArray, terms);
            idf = new TfIdf().idfCalculator(termsDocsArray, terms);
            tfidf = tf * idf;           
            //System.out.print(terms+"\t"+tfidf+"\t");
            //System.out.print(terms+"\t");

            tfidf = Math.round(tfidf*10000)/10000.0d;
            tfidfList.add(tfidf);
            maxValue=Collections.max(tfidfList);
            tfidf=(tfidf-minValue)/(maxValue-minValue);  //Normalization here
            mat[c][count]=Double.toString(tfidf);
            count++;   
        }     
    c++;
    }
```

This is the output I got

```
NaN 1.0  0.0  0.021
0.0 1.0 0.0 0.365 ... and others
```

only the first number is NAN, also this number is originally a number that is repeated many times in the matrix but its value is not NAN

Please give me some ideas to fix this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're dividing by zero. This will happen when the first value that is added to the `tfidflist` is `0.0`.

In order to perform a real *normalization*, you'll probably have to compute all possible values first, then compute the min/max of these values, and afterwards, normalize all values based on these min/max values. Roughly:

```
// First collect all values and compute min/max on the fly
double minValue=Double.MAX_VALUE;
double maxValue=-Double.MAX_VALUE;
double values = new String[termsDocsArray.size()][allTerms.size()];
int c=0; //for files
for (String[] docTermsArray : termsDocsArray) {
    int count = 0;//for words
    for (String terms : allTerms) {
        double tf = new TfIdf().tfCalculator(docTermsArray, terms);
        double idf = new TfIdf().idfCalculator(termsDocsArray, terms);
        double tfidf = tf * idf;           
        tfidf = Math.round(tfidf*10000)/10000.0d;
        minValue = Math.min(minValue, tfidf);
        maxValue = Math.max(maxValue, tfidf);
        values[c][count]=tfidf;
        count++;   
    }     
    c++;
}

// Then, create the matrix containing the strings of the normalized 
// values (although using strings here seems like a bad idea)
c=0; //for files
for (String[] docTermsArray : termsDocsArray) {
    int count = 0;//for words
    for (String terms : allTerms) {
        double tfidf = values[c][count];
        tfidf=(tfidf-minValue)/(maxValue-minValue);  //Normalization here
        mat[c][count]=Double.toString(tfidf);
        count++;   
    }     
    c++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Marco13.. please have a look to the edit. I tried what you suggest and I still have the same problem

Comment: @user1488019 Did you change the code to compute the min/max *before* normalizing? Just add the line `System.out.println("Dividing by "+(maxValue-minValue));` before you are normalizing, and make sure that it is never dividing by 0

Comment: Thank you another time @Marco13 but the problem is not about the operation itself. I noticed that the first number is not taken (ignored)

Comment: @user1488019 I'm not sure what you mean, and whether it is a question that can be answered here. If so, you may probably edit the original question and add a more detailed description of the actual question...

Answer (score 2):

My first guess is that you are dividing 0.0 by 0.0 -- maybe maxValue, minValue, and tfidf are all zero. My advice is to put a print statement just before the normalization step -- I'm guessing you'll see some unexpected values there.

Comment: Thank you @Robert. I already printed the results before and after the normalization step and there is nothing abnormal. please have a look to the edit I did to the question